# ZooKeeper ACL, allow children creation but not changing a node

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I'm considering a ZK server for service discovery with a focus on security. There could be multiple clusters (ZK directories created by a Source of truth), and multiple servers would create an ephemeral node to those directories.

Now, I don't want that any other ZK Client deletes, or modifies the ZK directories created by the source of truth. They should be able only to add ephemeral children to them to allow them to be discovered.

Is ZK the right tool? 
Which ACls should I set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, ZK is the right tool.

You can manage access permissions per nodes by setting [ACL permissions](http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.1.2/zookeeperProgrammers.html#sc_ACLPermissions)

Let's take an example with digest authentication. First let's generate password:

```
java -cp zookeeper-3.4.6.jar:lib/log4j-1.2.16.jar:lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar:lib/slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar org.apache.zookeeper.server.auth.DigestAuthenticationProvider u1:p1
u1:p1->u1:fpT/y03U+EjItKZOSLGvjnJlyng=
```

In zkCli session let's authenticate:

```
addauth digest u1:p1
```

For example you set permissions only to create child nodes and read current node and admin the node for authenticated users and just read permission for others:

```
[zk: localhost:2181(CONNECTED) 14] setAcl /source/of1 digest:u1:fpT/y03U+EjItKZOSLGvjnJlyng=:cra,world:anyone:r
[zk: localhost:2181(CONNECTED) 15] getAcl /source/of1
'digest,'u1:fpT/y03U+EjItKZOSLGvjnJlyng=
: cra
'world,'anyone
: r
```

Then it will be possible to create child nodes (both ephemeral and permanent) and read current node

```
set /source/of1 "jjj"
Authentication is not valid : /source/of1
[zk: localhost:2181(CONNECTED) 17] create -e /source/of1/truthEphemeral ""
Created /source/of1/truthEphemeral
[zk: localhost:2181(CONNECTED) 18] ls /source/of1
[truthEphemeral]
```

On other zkCli session let's try to read children of /source/of1 without authenticating:

```
[zk: localhost:2181(CONNECTED) 0] ls /source/of1
[truthEphemeral]
```

Now let's try to create new child node under that unauthenticated session:

```
[zk: localhost:2181(CONNECTED) 1] create -e /source/of1/truthEphemeral2 ""
Authentication is not valid : /source/of1/truthEphemeral2
```

Now let's authenticate with digest schema in that zkCli session and try to create new child node:

```
[zk: localhost:2181(CONNECTED) 2] addauth digest u1:p1
[zk: localhost:2181(CONNECTED) 3] create -e /source/of1/truthEphemeral2 ""
Created /source/of1/truthEphemeral2
```

For authentication you can use one of schemes supported out of the box or implement your own auth scheme using [zookeeper pluggable authentication](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.4.5/zookeeperProgrammers.html#sc_ZooKeeperPluggableAuthentication).

Comment: If you set 127.0.0.1, does it mean that nobody except a client on the leader server can change the node?

Comment: I've used ip schema just as an example. It's better to use at lease digest or implement your own auth schema and plug it into Zookeeper. Plugging into zookeeper is simply adding jar into lib directory on zookeeper server

Comment: Thanks. But if I set the source as ip:127.0.0.1:cra, other clients can't read, and only 127.0.0.1 could. Therefore I would need some linux like way to set permission: 127.0.0.1:all, world:cr, correct? How would you do that?

Comment: you are right, we need 2 ACLs: one for authenticated with cra permissions and another for other scheme with just READ permissions. I've updated the answer with that information and more detailed example using digest auth schema